# jQuery checkbox selector only works twice

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a few checkboxes in my ASP.NET solution that I am finding via their class and then checking them all with one button. This totally works fine for checking all and even unchecking them all when the button is pressed again, but after that it stops working entirely until the page is reloaded.

I thought everything was done correctly. Could you please have a look?

```
@for (int y = 0; y < Model.MainNodes[i].children.Count(); y++)
{
    string className = "langCheck rowCounter" + i;

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="">
                <table class="mytable">
                    <tr class="rowHeight">
                        <td class="column0">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MainNodes[i].children[y].IsChecked, new { @class = className })
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MainNodes[i].children[y].ItemId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MainNodes[i].children[y].GlobalTaggingId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MainNodes[i].children[y].ItemType)
                        </td>



function selectAll(idOfButton) {
    var className = '.rowCounter' + idOfButton
    
    $(className).each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', !$(this).attr('checked'));
    });
}
```

EDIT:

This is how I assign the button:

```
<button onclick="selectAll(@i)" class="buttonselectall" type="button">alle auswählen</button>
```

Comment: This is not an ASP question. Please create a [mcve] with relevant HTML, CSS and JS

Comment: How do you assign the click event handler?

Comment: @mplungjan, it could be. `@Html.HiddenFor` generates an input element with a name and id property if not specified otherwise so it can be a factor in the js not working.

Comment: If you post HTML instead of ASP we can solve this more elegantly

Comment: I don't see any element with a class name beginning with "rowCounter".